# nodejs session working locally but not on a remote server

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am not able to do a sign up and login using passort.js and express.js, locally this works very fine but when I deploy the app on a remote server the login fails to redirect me after logging. It does not even flash the failure messages.

I also noted that when I do a signup on the remote server it works fine but does not flash message.
req.isAuthenticated() always returns false.
I am using MongoDB as my datasource

```
app.use(session({secret : '3T67774A-R649-4D44-9735-43E296ZZ980F', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Request Authenticated: " + req.isAuthenticated());
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    res.redirect('/login');
}

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass in the req from our router (lets us check that a use is logged in or not
}, function(req, email, password, done) {
    if (email)
        email.toLowerCase(); // use lower-case emails to avoid case-sensitive email matching

    // asynchronous
    process.nextTick(function() {
        User.findOne({'local.email' : email}, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error
            if (err) 
                return done(err);

            // if no user found, return the message
            if (!user)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'User not found.'));

            if (!user.isValidPassword(password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.'));

            // return user
            else
                return done(null, user);
        });
    });
}));
```

Comment: Maybe this is not the solution to your problem, but you definitely should be declaring your LocalStrategy before you initialize the passport & the session, give it a try!

Comment: Also, note that `email.toLowerCase();` *returns* the value of the string converted to lowercase, it does not affect the value of the string `email` itself. The correct syntax would therefor be `email = email.toLowerCase();`.

Comment: but that does not seem to affect login since the email object now is set to lowercase and any reference to it returns lowercase, the primary concern is why login cannot work on a remote server, the POST seems to fail totally, it kinds of just refresh the login page

Comment: @GeorgeOtieno Did you solve this issue ? Could you post an answer if you were able to solve it ?