# Passport auth works locally but not on remote server

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm going crazy about this problem. I've just setup Passport js together with Google oAuth 2.0 strategy and it works perfect on my local Express 4 server.

But when I try to run it on my Amazon server the call *req.isAuthenticated()* returns false every time and *req.user* is undefined. I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
   console.log("serializeUser " + user.id);
   done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
   console.log("deserializeUser: " + id);
   User.find({_id: id}, function (error, user) {
       if (error || !user) {
           done(error, null);
       } else {
           done(null, user);
       }
   });
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: config.google.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.google.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.google.callbackURL
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    process.nextTick(function () {

        if(profile._json.domain === 'xxx'){

            var query = {googleId: profile.id};
            var options = {upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true };

            // Find the document
            User.findOneAndUpdate(query, query , options, function (error, user) {
                if (error) {
                    return done(error);
                }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }else{
            return done(new Error("Invalid host domain"));
        }
    });

}
));

router.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'] }));

router.get('/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
});

router.get('/login', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
     console.log("User is Authenticated");
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {

   console.log("USER " + req.user);

   if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      console.log("Authorized");
      return next();
   } else {
      console.log("Not authorized");
      res.sendStatus(401);
   }

}
```

And this is the Express server conf.

```
/ Express
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser('xxx'));

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '100mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '100mb', extended: true}));

// Used for production build
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
    store: sessionStore, //var sessionStore = new MemoryStore();
    secret: 'xxx',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    }
}));

// Compress responses
app.use(compression());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

routes(app);
```

[Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678597/nodejs-session-working-locally-but-not-on-a-remote-server)

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I think my problem was fixed by switching the Session Store to MongoStore instead of MemoryStore. I hope that saves some time for some of you in the future.

```
 // Express
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser('xxx'));

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '100mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '100mb', extended: true}));

// Used for production build
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
    cookieName: 'session',
    duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
        touchAfter: 24 * 3600 // time period in seconds
    }),
    secret: 'xxx',
    saveUninitialized: false, // don't create session until something stored
    resave: false, //don't save session if unmodified
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the amazon server to the list of authorized redirect URIs? See the following : https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication#oauth2_playground

Make sure to add your Amazon redirect URI to google's console in order to authenticate